# Change color trace in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplot graphic and I need to change the color trace under specific criteria.
The X axis is Date+time ('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S') and the Y axis are float values.
I have a list with those data:

```
List=[6/12/20 13:51:43 45.3, 6/12/20 13:59:19 46.1 19 X, 6/12/20 14:1:43 46.2, 6/12/20 14:11:43 47.1, 6/12/20 14:14:6 46.5 28 X, 6/12/20 14:17:41 46.5 25 X, 6/12/20 14:19:59 46.0 35 X]
```

As you can see, every element in the list are: '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S' FloatValue Seconds Event
If one element has the X event, I need to change the colour of the trace to another for the whole period. Thus, the second item on the list has the X event for 19 seconds ( that is the event start at 6/12/20 13:59:00 and finalice at 6/12/20 13:59:19) so the trace color should be changed in that period.
So for more friendly data, I do this:

```
dates = ['6/12/20 13:51:43', '6/12/20 13:59:19', '6/12/20 14:1:43', '6/12/20 14:11:43', '6/12/20 14:14:6', '6/12/20 14:17:41', '6/12/20 14:19:59']

y = [45.3, 46.1, 46.2, 47.1, 46.5, 46.5, 46.0]
```

Below, you can see the code but without the time of the events because I dont know how to handle those values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

dates = ['6/12/20 13:51:43', '6/12/20 13:59:19', '6/12/20 14:1:43', '6/12/20 14:11:43', '6/12/20 14:14:6', '6/12/20 14:17:41', '6/12/20 14:19:59']
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S') for d in dates]
print(x)
y = [45.3, 46.1, 46.2, 47.1, 46.5, 46.5, 46.0]

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=5))

plt.grid()
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), size=8)

plt.legend()
plt.plot(x,y, marker='o')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

I dont know how to do this, any idea???

Answer (score 0):

You can define specific masks for the date and use them to differentiate the "segments" you want for the line. There are several different ways to do this. The "best" approach will depend mostly on how many line segments you want to plot.

If you're just going to be plotting a handful (e.g. 10) line segments, then just do something like:

Refer below example for more details.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

font = {'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   :  18 }
plt.rc('font', **font)

def uniqueish_color():
    """There're better ways to generate unique colors, but this isn't awful."""
    return plt.cm.gist_ncar(np.random.random())

xy = (np.random.random((10, 2)) - 0.5).cumsum(axis=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
for start, stop in zip(xy[:-1], xy[1:]):
    x, y = zip(start, stop)
    ax.plot(x, y,lw=3, color=uniqueish_color())
plt.grid()
```

[image]